# Phase spaces for second order differential equations - Arnold's ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, mathematical-modeling

this is my first post here, so please excuse me if I do anything wrong

I'm a high school student, and my question is about phase planes, which I got interested in after learning about differential equations. In Arnold's ODE book, he introduces the notion of a phase plane here:

[image: 2-dimensional phase space]

This phase plane seems to be different from other vector fields I've seen, which has normally axes $x$ against $t$, or $y$ against $x$. It seems to be different because it is '2 dimensional' and that this case arises for second order differential equations. Gilbert Strang's course on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqXKa11IA6A) also introduces this, but doesn't explicitly explain why the axes of the phase plane are $y'$ and $y$. A comment in the video said that it is because 'any second order ODE can be transformed into a system of 2 first order ODEs'.

My question is that I do not understand the process of defining the coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$ of the phase space to be the position and velocity, instead of maybe the velocity and time, or using a three dimensional vector field, with position velocity and time. I know that time is specific to this case, which is time-dependent, but is time somehow built into the solution to the differential equation? I am not sure where time fits into this and how we can interpret the phase space without time.

It would be helpful enough to point me in any further reading I would have to do to understand this, instead of a full answer if possible. I have tried to look for an explanation which relates creating phase plots to transforming second order equations to a system of first order ones, but to no avail. Thanks very much to anyone who can help!

References:

1. [What is "Phase Space" in differential equations and classical mechanics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595671/what-is-phase-space-in-differential-equations-and-classical-mechanics)
2. [What is the defininition of phase Space in simple terms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552057/what-is-the-defininition-of-phase-space-in-simple-terms)
3. [Arnold's ODE computation of phase velocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685886/arnolds-ode-computation-of-phase-velocity)

Comment: A particular solution of a 2nd order ODE is uniquely defined by the initial position and the initial velocity of the  particle. That's why phase space becomes important. The curves in it describe all possible solutions. Since you found already three References about the topic it is hard to decide what more one could say. Keep studying and let it sink in.

Comment: Would that help? Phase space is another word for state space or domain of the (or some fixed) first-order system. What you have is a diagram of the vector field "view" of the first-order system (often called "quiver" in procedure names). Another popular diagram is the phase portrait that contains a space-filling selection of short or longer segments of solutions of the ODE (also called "stream plot" as function name).

Comment: @KurtG. ok I will try to expose myself to more of these cases. One final question is how time will play into this though - to me it seems like a big jump to go from a plot with x and t to a plot that doesn’t explicitly have time as the coordinate. Is the time quantity built into the phase plans already, and how so?